# Archlinux ARM: Error: failed to init transaction (unable to lock database)

Tags: linux, archlinux-arm

So i am new to arch linux and i am following a guide to get KDE plasma installed, so i've go going along through this script and now all of a sudden i get the following error:

> Archlinux ARM: Error: failed to init transaction (unable to lock database)
>   error: could not lock database: read-only file system

and the command i am using is:

> pacman -S kf5 kf5-aids

Now from the fact that i know how to read i see that the second error states that all files are currently read only. What i want to know is how or what would have caused that to happen and how to fix my all round issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have root privileges?

Try sudo*ing*:

```
# sudo pacman -S kf5 kf5-aids
```

If you haven't installed (and configured) sudo, just log in as root:

```
# su -
```

And execute the command under the new user.